# Visual Studio 2010: How to generate documentation out of code comments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I wrote some comments for my code. Now how can I generate a documentation or something similar with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your build properties tab, enable XML documentation and use [Sandcastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) to build a help/documentation file.

Comment: Thanks but any hints how to use sandcastle? The homepage is a little bit weird.

Comment: Have a look at this one - http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/ - it has documentation and everything. (That's the one I use).

Comment: I changed the link to http://shfb.codeplex.com .  http://sandcastle.codeplex.com says it is no longer under active development, and www.sandcastledocs.com appears to be a link farm.

Comment: The new repository location for Sandcastle is here (https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB). Still under active development as of June 2017.

Answer (score 4):

I describe a Tool for visual studio

### VSdocman - Visual Studio code commenter and documentation generator

Document your .NET code on a professional level.

Generate comprehensive MSDN-style class documentation for your C# and Visual Basic .NET projects, with custom topics, IntelliSense and F1 context sensitive help.

See how easy the code commenting can be with powerful comment templates and sophisticated WYSIWYG comment editor.

VSdocman is an ultimate API documenting tool for every Visual Studio developer - whether you create a class library, a component, a control, an application, a smart device or a web site (ASP .NET).

### screenshot

[image]

[image]

[image]
[Web Site](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/). The NDoc is outdated, but there is [NDoc3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc3/). [More alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-documentation-generator)

Comment: It's too bad the project looks dead. Last version was released in 2005. =(

Comment: Yes. How do you install it? I tried but it's always complaining that i use a too new version of .NET framework :D

Comment: Yes its out dated. Try with NDoc3 http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc3/

Answer (score 2):

Another well known (external) system for generating documentation is [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

Comment: Thanks i tried it and it looks also really nice.

Answer (score 2):

1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
2. Click the Build tab.
3. On the Build page, select XML documentation file. By default, the
   file is created under the specified output path, for example,
   "bin\Debug\Projectname.XML".

[How to: Generate XML Documentation for a Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4sa0ak0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) along with Sandcastle. [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) is a GUI for Sandcastle and takes away all your pain while using Sandcastle.