# Generation of a project documentation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, documentation

I am not finding the different names of the different software which generate a documentation (Readme.txt) from the comments mentioned on the different Header and Cpp files, directly extracted from a visual studio solution C++ / project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010: How to generate documentation out of code comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301437/visual-studio-2010-how-to-generate-documentation-out-of-code-comments)

Comment: @mnemonic
No I am sorry. I am dealing with C++ and not Csharp.

Comment: For the last 5 to 6 years (at work) I have used doxygen to generate my documentation for my visual studio c++ code. Although if you do not comment every class ... the usefulness of the generated documentation for your users is not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [Sandcastle help file builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/). It is a set of tools that generate documentation in different formats from the XML comments in the source files.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered within [this SO url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301437/visual-studio-2010-how-to-generate-documentation-out-of-code-comments)

Another point of view, consideration of [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) (only applied for Perl in my case but usable for C# in addition)

A couple of years ago, [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) was suitable. Maybe that would not be working for VS 10.