# Equivalente javadoc in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, javadoc

I need your help to know about javadoc in asp.net, does exist any javadoc equivalent for .net (asp.net mvc 4)?. I know about `///summary` but I don't know if this comments can be exported to xml or html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this answer on how to enable XML documentation directly on VS: 
[How to generate documentation out of code comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301437/visual-studio-2010-how-to-generate-documentation-out-of-code-comments)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into GhostDoc?
http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx